# .Net Make how to make sure a checkbox is checked

Tags: asp.net, validation

Using Asp.net Webforms how can I validate that a checkbox has been checked. (I cannot do a postback) has to be in javascript (either custom - working with the existing validation controls for other fields. or using a .net validation control)

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a CustomValidator control and specify an ClientValidationFunction javascript function.

Find more info here:
http://forums.aspfree.com/net-development-11/compare-validator-for-a-checkbox-121590.html

But if you're only doing client-side validation, the whole CustomValidator implementation might be a bit useless. Just validate the checkbox with javascript on the form submit.

Answer (score 1):

in jquery

```
if ($('#checkBoxID').attr('checked'))
{
    //code
}
```

in normal javascript

```
if (getElementById('checkBoxID').checked)
{
    //code
}
```

Comment: You can use this type of code in the client script of a custom validator

Answer (score 1):

```
if (document.getElementById("check_box_id").checked) {
  // it is checked
}
else {
  // it is not
}
```

Or with jQuery:

```
if ($(("#check_box_id").attr("checked") == true) {
  // it is checked
}
else {
  // it is not
}
```